# Office 365 deployment using SCCM

Tags: office365, sccm

I am trying to deploy Office 365 to 700 users across the business, deploying this through SCCM is the most efficient way of doing this but I am unable to find an MSI or any information about how to do this. Microsoft supply something called a deployment tool, but I'm a bit confused how to use this as when I click to run, nothing happens. Any light shed on this would be greatly appreciated. My thinking is to download office 365 myself and when it downloads the suite then to use those installation files using the deployment tool?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the deployment tool.  Along with that, there is an XML file you configure for download and distribution.  The download part of the XML tells the tool what to download and where.  The deployment part of the XML tell's it which apps are going to be installed, and how they are going to be updated.

Microsoft actually has a step by step for creating and deploying the package thru SCCM.  Just Google/Bing "**Deploy Office 365 ProPlus by using System Center Configuration Manager**"

Currently, that resource lives here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn708063.aspx

For more general information on the deployment tool, and other scenarios use "**Deploy Click-to-Run for Office 365 products by using the Office Deployment Tool**", and that page is currently hosted here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219423.aspx